# Extract numeric values with inch notation in a string and return larger one

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extract size information from products having names like.

```
Product A 30" Metalic Grey
Product B 31.50" Led 54 watt
Product C 40"-60" Dark Green
```

My current code to fetch size information is

```
var product_name = $(this).text();
product_name.split('"')[0].slice(-2);
```

I am having difficulty to deal sizes with points for example 31.50".

Is there a better way to extract sizes from above example product names also for product names like third product with size range it needs to return the bigger numeric value which is 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all sizes from a string, you can use the [**regular expression**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `[\d.]+(?=")`:

```
var sizes = text.match(/[\d.]+(?=")/g);
```

This will return an [**array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object) of strings, such as `["31.50"]` or `["40", "60"]`.

You can further process the array, e.g. convert the elements to numbers:

```
sizes = sizes.map(Number); // ["31.50"] -> [31.50]
```

and/or get the maximum value:

```
var maxSize = Math.max.apply(null, sizes); // ["40", "60"] -> 60
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
product_name.replace(/^.*?([\d\.]+)"[^"]*$/, '$1');
```

Comment: one problem: it doesnt work in a scenario like 20"-10" it still returns 10 where as it should return the bigger value 20

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to separate at the first `"` symbol, then find the last space before it:

```
var product_name = $(this).text();
var size = product_name.split('"')[0];
var space = product_name.lastIndexOf(' ');
size.slice(space, -1);
```

That'll give you everything from `"`, then back to the space before it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will use a regex to find the strings then return the largest, run through each example string:

```
var t = [
    'Product A 30" Metalic Grey',
    'Product B 31.50" Led 54 watt',
    'Product C 40"-60" Dark Green'
]

var getMaxInches = function(str) {
    var inches = str.match(/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?"/g); // The inches format pattern


    var maxMeasure = 0;
    for(i in inches){

        var measure =  (inches[i]).slice(0,-1); // remove the trailing "
        maxMeasure = Math.max(Number(measure),maxMeasure);
    }

    return maxMeasure;
}

for(var i in t) alert(getMaxInches(t[i]));
```